# How to add an Islamic calendar to a public calendar?

Tags: php, time, calendar

I have this script. The code below shows the usual calendar

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="view-calendar">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Monday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Tuesday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Wednesday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Thursday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Friday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Saturday</td>
<td valign="top" width="14.2857%">Sunday</td>
</tr>

<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');

$days_count = date('t');

$current_day = date('d');

// save time of first day for later use
$time_first_day_of_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));

$week_day_first = date('N', $time_first_day_of_month);

// Get next month dates
$next_start = strtotime(date("Y-m-00", strtotime("+1 month")));

$next_dates = array();

for ($w = 1 - $week_day_first + 1; $w <= $days_count; $w = $w + 7){
  echo '<tr>';
  $counter = 0;
    for ($d = $w; $d <= $w + 6; $d++){
      if($d < 10){
        $current_date = date("Y").date("m").'0'.$d;
      }else{
        $current_date = date("Y").date("m").$d;
      }
      echo '<td valign="top" width="14.2857%"'.(($d > 0 ? ($d > $days_count ? ' class="disabled"' : '') : ' class="disabled"')).(($counter > 4 ? ' class="week-day"' : '')).'>';
      if($d > 0){
        // next month's dates
        if($d > $days_count){
          for($in = 1; $in <= 1; $in++){
            echo array_push($next_dates, date('j', strtotime("+ $in day", $next_start)));
          }
        }
        // today
        else if($current_day == $d){
          echo '<div class="current-day" style="font-weight: bold;color:red;"><span class="given-date">'.$d.'</span></div>';
        }
        // this month's dates
        else{
          echo '<span class="given-date">'.$d.'</span>';
        }
      }
      // last month's dates
      else{
        //Here comes previous dates
        $offset = $d - 1;
        echo '<span class="given-date">'.date('d', strtotime("$offset day",$time_first_day_of_month)).'</span>';
      }
      echo '</td>';
      $counter++;
    }
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

I want to create an Islamic calendar like this https://www.islamicfinder.org/islamic-calendar/. How to combine it with islamic calendar? And I do not know how to calculate to get the calendar result of Islam

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.